# Chrome developer tools not providing link to source?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Was debugging a particularly nasty bug today and hit this problem in the Chrome Developer Tools:

[image]

As you can see, I added a `console.log()`, which usually lets you click on the right and take you to the source....but in this case there was no source link.

Doing a 'cmd+alt+F' search (ie. global search) comes up with nothing either.

Anyone hit this problem before/know how to get to the correct source files?

Comment: Is this in dynamically loaded JS?

Comment: Do you mean CMD+ALT+F? CMD+SHIFT+F gets me into fullscreen mode.

Comment: Oops, yes I meant "cmd+alt+f" - edited! Yes, it is dynamically loaded.